# Is Indra's vehicle Airavata a Naga?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, indra, naga

According to Astika Parva section XXXV, Airavata is the third son of Kadru and Kashyap

> Sesha was born first, and then Vasuki. (Then were born) **Airavata**, Takshaka, Karkotaka, Dhananjaya, Kalakeya, the serpent Mani, Purana, Pinjaraka, and Elapatra, Vamana, Nila, Anila, Kalmasha, Savala, Aryaka, Ugra, Kalasapotaka, Suramukha, Dadhimukha, Vimalapindaka, Apta, Karotaka, Samkha, Valisikha, Nisthanaka, Hemaguha, Nahusha, Pingala, Vahyakarna, Hastipada, Mudgarapindaka, Kamvala Aswatara, Kaliyaka, Vritta, Samvartaka, Padma, Mahapadma, Sankhamukha, Kushmandaka, Kshemaka, Pindaraka, Karavira, Pushpadanshtraka, Vilwaka,

I wanted to confirm if this is the same Airavata as Indra's

Answer (score 3):

No. This Airavata is different. Aravata (elephant) was not son of Kasyapa. Kaśyapa married Dakṣa’s daughter, Krodhavaśā who bore him ten daughters. They were: Mṛgī, Mṛgamandā, Harī, Bhadramatā, Mātaṅgī, Śārdūlī, Svetā, Surabhī, Sarasā and Kadru. Of these Bhadramatā had a daughter named Irāvatī and Airāvata was her son whom was an elephant. aathis genealogy is given in Valmiki Ramyana.

> "Oh, Rama, Krodhavasha gave birth to ten of her self-same daughters
> namely Mrigi, Mrigamanda, Hari, Bhadramanda, Maatangii, Sharduulii,
> Shweta, Surabhii, and like that to Surasa, who is embodied with all
> giftedness, and even to Kadruva. [3-14-21, 22]
>
> "Children Mrigi are all of the the deer, oh best of the best-men,
> Rama, and Mrigamnda's progeny is Riksha-s, Bears, a kind of antelope,
> and like that the Himalayan yak like species.[3-14-23]
>
> "Then Bhadramanda gave birth to the girl named Iravati and **her son is
> elephant the great, Airaavata, the protector of world.** [3-14-24]

In [Agni Puarana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083107.html), he is called the king of elephants so he can't be a naga.

> 27. The Airāvata (was made the ruler) among the lords of elephants, bull of the kine and the tiger, of the animals, (and) Plakṣa (the Indian fig-tree) (as) the lord of trees.

On the other hand, King Airavata (serpent) was a king of nagas.

> "Ye **Serpents, subjects of King Airavata**, splendid in battle and showering weapons in the field like lightning-charged clouds driven by the winds! Handsome and of various forms and decked with many coloured ear-rings, ye children of Airavata, ye shine like the Sun in the firmament! On the northern banks of the Ganges are many habitations of serpents. There I constantly adore the great serpents. Who except Airavata would desire to move in the burning rays of the Sun? When Dhritarashtra (Airavata's brother) goes out, twenty-eight thousand and eight serpents follow him as his attendants. Ye who move near him and ye who stay at a distance from him, I adore all of you that have Airavata for your elder brother.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought Nagaraja Airavata and Indra's vahana would be the same entity since both Nagas and Indras had a friendly relationship.

Comment: @Varma Thanks. if u r satisfied with the answer. Pls give me the acceptance tick✔️